# 500 Error for AWS API Gateway Connection to Private Endpoint

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ecs

I've created an ECS Cluster using Cloudformation from this template (https://github.com/cmanikandan/fargate-apigateway/blob/master/fargate-private-subnet-network-loadbalancer.yml) running a flask app on port 80 (see dockerfile below) and connecting API Gateway through the private VPC link to the application load balancer (see aws cli code below). For a first step I'm trying to configure only a GET method at root (/).

I've been able to get this to work for the example in this aws blogpost (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/access-private-applications-on-aws-fargate-using-amazon-api-gateway-privatelink/) however when I try it with my application from ECR I run into a 500 error `(Execution failed due to configuration error: There was an internal error while executing your request)`.

**Where have I gone wrong in configuration? Potentially something having to do with port mapping?**

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["python", "app.py", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

**AWS CLI Commands for API Gateway:**

```
aws apigateway create-vpc-link \
--name REMOVED \
--target-arns REMOVED \
--region us-west-2

aws apigateway get-vpc-link --vpc-link-id REMOVED --region us-west-2

aws apigateway create-rest-api --name 'Fargate Test' --region us-west-2

aws apigateway get-resources --rest-api-id REMOVED --region us-west-2 

aws apigateway put-method \
       --rest-api-id REMOVED \
       --resource-id REMOVED \
       --http-method ANY \
       --authorization-type "NONE" --region us-west-2

aws apigateway put-integration \
--rest-api-id REMOVED \
--resource-id REMOVED \
--uri 'http://myApi.example.com' \
--http-method ANY \
--type HTTP_PROXY \
--integration-http-method ANY \
--connection-type VPC_LINK \
--connection-id REMOVED --region us-west-2

aws apigateway create-deployment \
--rest-api-id REMOVED \
--stage-name REMOVED \
--variables vpcLinkId=REMOVED--region us-west-2
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being that I didn't expose the port in my dockerfile for the Network Load Balancer to be able to route traffic from the API Gateway end point.

vvv This is the solution vvv

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["python", "app.py", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```